# How to exclude some members from being serialized to Json?

Tags: .net, json, serialization

I have an object that I want to serialize to Json format
I'm using:

```
    public string ToJson()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string sJSON = jsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
        return sJSON;
    }
```

How do I define some fields in "this" to not be serialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possible way is to declare those fields as `private` or `internal`.

The alternative solution is to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` class. In this case you add `DataContract` attribute to your class. You can control the members you want to serialize with `DataMember` attribute - all members marked with it are serialized, and the others are not.

You should rewrite your ToJson method as follows:

```
    public string ToJson()
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = 
              new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(<your class name>));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        jsonSerializer.WriteObject(ms, this);
        string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Dispose();
        return json;
    }
```

Answer (score 23):

Use the [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx).

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer.  I'm glad I read through the answers to the bottom, or I would've missed this.  Works beautifully.

Comment: @karaxuna, it is supported down to 3.5 (which is when the JavascriptSerializer was introduced)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) class.  You can [register converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx) to customize the serialization/deserialization process for specific object types.  You can then include the properties that you want, without making any changes to the original class.

Comment: Nice, but i be still difficult if I want a string member to be serialized while another string member to be not. right?

Comment: You basically return a dictionary of key/value pairs, so it would be up to your custom converter to simply include one and not the other.  You could even serialize each member (or not) based on its value.